# how to trap user inputs C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, user-input

I've been learning c# by myself for weeks. things are new to me as i am not familiar with the syntax and techniques on how to write an efficient program.

today i wonder how a good programmer deal with user inputs errors. what i mean is, when i ask the users to input their name,

Console.Write("pls input ur name");

and the user inputs numbers, the program will run onto error.
what i am doing is that i use string variable.

string inputs;

but it displays everything even a numerical value which is not a name.

how could i deal with this kind of error? how can i trap user inputs? how can i allow the user to only input the value i want?

*this is my first time using stack overflow thanks for having me here

Comment: The phrase you want is `input validation`.  Google reports 137,000 posts on SO alone.

Comment: The good system design doesn't accept bad input. It's inform the user that the input is not valid or in some cases warning the user if he really want to go with the input. Learn how to validate input data on Google. I found this on Google https://codeasy.net/lesson/input_validation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class Program
{

  static void Main()
  {
    string strName;
    do
    {
      Console.WriteLine("What is your name, please?");
      strName = Console.ReadLine();
      foreach ( char c in strName )
        if ( !char.IsLetter(c) )
        {
          Console.WriteLine();
          Console.WriteLine("Your name can only contains letters.");
          Console.WriteLine();
          strName = null;
          break;
        }
    }
    while ( strName == null );
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + strName);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }

}
```

If name can have space or any key like '-', the test condition is like:

```
if ( !char.IsLetter(c) && c!= ' ')
```

An advanced solution is to use a while ReadKey() and to catch all keys to edit and reject chars that are not letters, so the user can only use letters keys. It requires to manage keys such as arrows, del, backspace, home, end, enter, escape... and to resend to the console according to the UX desired.

Comment: thanks for this! ill try to make my a play around using this method you've provided.