# How to restrict user input in the console

Tags: c#, .net, terminal

I'm fairly new to c# and was wondering how I could restrict a users input from the terminal. As is, you can type something and hit enter, even before the readline comes up. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch key from keyboard in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58109201/how-to-catch-key-from-keyboard-in-c-sharp/) & [how to trap user inputs C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57945832/how-to-trap-user-inputs-c-sharp/)

Comment: Which console are you using that displays a redline?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are actually looking for is Console.ReadKey().

This function returns a `ConsoleKeyInfo` structure which contains a lot of information on the key pressed.  I'm not sure what you mean by "restrict" the input from user terminal, but I assume it means that you want to be able to tell which keys they pressed before pressing enter.  This will allow you to do that:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
do
{
  keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
  // do whatever you want with keyInfo here,
  // in this case I'll just print it
  Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
} while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
```